# Agregar 2 inputs uno al lado del otro en la misma fila

Tags: php, css

Estoy intentando crear un formulario, y quiero que en una fila haya 2 input, uno al lado del otro.
Lo logro hacer con Bootstrap, pero modifica la apariencia de mi pagina WEB y no se como evitar que eso no pase, es por eso que me gustaría alinear los 2 input solo con CSS.

```
<label for="dd_mm_inicio"><i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i> Fecha Inicio Práctica</label>
            <input type="text" REQUIRED name="dd_mm_inicio" id="dd_mm_inicio">

            <label for="dd_mm_termino"><i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i> Fecha Termino 
 Práctica</label>
            <input type="text" REQUIRED name="dd_mm_termino" id="dd_mm_termino">
```

Comment: ¿Quieres que los labels estén en la misma línea que el input o encima?

Comment: Los Labels encima del input, o incluso puedo quitar los labels y colocar el nombre en un PLACEHOLDER

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es muy fácil con una combinación de grid o flex:

```css
.input_div{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.input_container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="input_container">
  <div class="input_div">
    <label for="dd_mm_inicio"><i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i> Fecha Inicio Práctica</label>
    <input type="text" REQUIRED name="dd_mm_inicio" id="dd_mm_inicio">
  </div>

  <div class="input_div">
    <label for="dd_mm_termino"><i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i> Fecha Termino 
    Práctica</label>
    <input type="text" REQUIRED name="dd_mm_termino" id="dd_mm_termino">
  </div>
</div>
```

Si solo ocupas los inputs:

```css
.input_container{
  display: flex;
  gap: 12px;
}

.input_container input{
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="input_container">
  <input type="text" REQUIRED name="dd_mm_inicio" id="dd_mm_inicio">
  <input type="text" REQUIRED name="dd_mm_termino" id="dd_mm_termino">
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono